# how to store datagridview name in a variable c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagrid

I used c# to start a project.
 In main form there is a datagridview, and I used the name of this datagrid in project repeatedly.

now I want to put the name of this datagrid in a variable and use that variable instead of datagrid name, so in the future, if datagrid target change,I just need to change the variable.

I try somthing like this:

`string myDataGridName = originalDataGridName`

```
myDataGridName.DataSource = null;//clear dataGrid
```

but this is wrong. then I search to find an answer and just find this link:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24082388/storing-datagridview-name-in-a-variable)
this link answer in .net, and I don't know about that... so please answer in c#

thank you

(sorry about my bad English)

Comment: Based on the question, the answer below is the only way to do this. You can't just change the name of the datasource. You need to keep track of the object itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to store a reference to the datagrid object itself. Then you can just change this in one place like you want. The example you posted is actually already very close.

```
DataGridView myDataGrid = originalDataGridViewObject;
myDataGrid.DataSource = null; //clear dataGrid
```

Of course, depending on your use case, this may not really be needed. In Visual Studio if you rename an object in the designer the associated code should be automatically renamed as well.

Comment: thank you! its work... I need this because the target datagrid(not the name of that datagrid) change in the future.

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help. Please be sure to click the checkmark to the left to mark the question as answered. Thanks!